# Python check if span class exists

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

So basically I want to get an output on boolean mode if a span class exists or no, but I don't know which libraries to use

```
<span class="Smth">
  Smth
</span>
```

I have tried searching some tutorials for requests but I didnt find anything

Comment: For HTML parsing, [beautiful soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this;

```
html = '<span class="Smth">Smth</span>'

if html.find('span class="Smth"') == -1:
    print(False)

else:
    print(True)
```

If you want to use any library then you can try [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="Smth">Smth</span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

if soup.find('span', class_='Smth'):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: What if I want to check the whole website if this code exists?